# Testing Drools DRL with postman

Tags: json, drools

Created a test Drools DRL and using postman to execute it.
When I send the request I use content-type application/json.
The rule execution work as I expected, but the return content-type is application/xml and not content-type application/json. Note: the response is json not xml. What do I need to do to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

In postman once you get the response 
there will be a drop down with type of data. instead of xml choose json.
[image]

Comment: I understand, but don't know why the kie-server is responding with a xml content-type and not a json content-type. It's returning json?

Comment: if I can get a code snippet and postman screen shot may be I can understand more

Comment: Fixed the issue, had to add header "accept: application/json to the request